# How to save a file using PHP?

Tags: php

I'm currently making subscribe form, I got the HTML ready but I got problems in the PHP:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
?>
```

Now I got them using php, how can I save them.

I need like to save them anywhere so I can like check them anytime.

like I would open a .txt where it saves and then I find the list of emails and names and messages.

Comment: It seems that you don't have experience with databases, but this is what you need to learn. Try to read and study about MySQL, MongoDB or similar in order you can store your user's information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @prakhar19, a database is better suited to store this kind of info. But if you really want to store this information in a file on the server (because you don't want to setup a database server just for this), go for [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
file_put_contents('subscribers.txt',
    $_POST['name'] . '\n' . $_POST['email'] . '\n' . $_POST['message'],
    FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Thanks Glorfindel Alot!! but a question , I am trying to make like every form in a line and the "\n" it doesn't work. do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Just use a comma instead of the `\n`.

Answer (score -2):

You need to make a database for saving the info. Google for '`Databases`' and '`MySql`'.

Comment: Thats my problem I need somone to help me to connect the database...

I mean I can easily make a MYSQL database but I got no idea how to connect it or let the php creates the table or any of those :(

Is there any tutorial I can follow